# Flask Print Not Working

Tags: python, json, flask

If I send run this program to do a HTTP Post to my Flask server, which I know returns a 200 response:

```
import requests
import json
dump= '{"on": false}'
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', data=dump,
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

And my Flask server's code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(content)
        print(jsonify(content))
        r = requests.put("http://192.168.1.102/api/F5La7UpN6XueJZUts1QdyBBbIU8dEvaT1EZs1Ut0/lights/5/state/", jsonify(content))
    else:
         return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to print the data to the console, then send it over to a bridge on the network using a HTTP PUT. Neither of these are working, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `return` **exits the function**. Anything you try to execute after `return` is simply never reached. So when the code reaches `return jsonify(content)` it doesn't matter what code follows, that code is never executed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return at the very end of the function

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.get_json()
        print(content)
        r = requests.put("http://192.168.1.102/api/F5La7UpN6XueJZUts1QdyBBbIU8dEvaT1EZs1Ut0/lights/5/state/", content)
        return jsonify(content)
    else:
         return 'Hello, world!'
```

Note: You probably are over-using the `jsonify` function because the `jsonify()` function in flask returns `flask.Response()` object, and not a JSON string that you would POST or PUT to another service.

Comment: So I would only want to use jsonify if I am sending a response back to the sending device?

Comment: To the client requesting an HTTP response, yes.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I should have understood the return thing as well, sorry. My last thing is that is their a way to keep the HTTP POST of `'{"on": false}'` as the apostrophes get removed, then meaning the PUT does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means... I'm only addressing the problem you asked about initially. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.